# Drawing Rectangle at random position after touch event in canvas Android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle at random positions in the `Canvas` (should not exceed the canvas dimensions) and if the user touches the shape, it should draw at another random position. I have managed to draw the rectangle but need help with `Touch Event` and drawing it at random positions after.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like given below:

**For example**

```
  public class DrawView extends View {

     // here you define hashmap for user touch points

      Paint paint = new Paint();

  public DrawView(Context context) {
      super(context);            
  }

  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      yourRandomFunction(-99,-99);


  }

  public void yourRandomFunction(float x , float y ){
     //for first time user touch 
     // if -99 && -99 { 
    //Calculate random points here.

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );
    // add points to hashmap
}
//else check in hashmap if exist then {
  //Calculate random points here.
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );
    // add point to hashmap
 } 

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      float eventX = event.getX();
       float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      //check points in hashmap 

      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      yourRandomFuncntion(eventX,eventY);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you got your solutin kindly tick my answer.

Comment: when does it redraw the rectangle?

Comment: can you use my code to make it work because that way I understand it more and yes I will tick your answer

Comment: you just need to create a method draw random in your class that will be called when  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  // nothing to do
  break;

Comment: +1 for the answer though. will tick it when you got my code in there too.

Comment: yes I knwo but I need help with doing the draw method as sometimes teh shape doesnt draw inside the canvas

Comment: Also at the moment, the shape is drawn at random position if the user touches anywhere on the screen, I want it to draw randomly only when the user touches the shape

Comment: i have edit the answer check that out. you got the idea in a better way i hope.

Comment: Hi, your answer works but Also at the moment, the shape is drawn at random position if the user touches anywhere on the screen, I want it to draw randomly only when the user touches the shape

Comment: create hashmap in which each touch user will be recieved and befor drawing on the screen just check if these points exist in the hashmap already

Comment: Hi Danial, I am not sure how to do this but if you do that for me I will tick you best answer. Thanks so much my friend

Comment: i just mention the algorithm in the form of comments inside my answer you need to do your self because i am busy right now.thanks

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Please help when you have time my friend. Appreciate this so much

Comment: `invalidate()` is the key here.